# Large sets and Erdős-discrepancy

Tags: combinatorics, natural-numbers, conjectures, erdos-conjecture

[Large Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_set_(combinatorics)) 
[Erdos conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_sequence)

I have a conjecture that is stronger than the Erdos discrepancy conjecture, can someone think of a counter example?

Let $S$ be any large set and let $(x_1,x_2,...)$ be any infinite $\pm 1$ sequence, then for any integer $C$, we can find an integer $k$ and an $s \in S $ so that $\sum_{i=1}^k|x_{i \cdot s}| > C$

I also think that the inverse is true. Thus, if $S$ is small there exists an  integer $C$ and some $(x_1,x_2,...)$ so  for every   $s$ and $k$  we have that $\sum_{i=1}^k|x_{i \cdot s}| <C$

Comment: Define what you mean bny "large set" (your link just goes to stackoverflow.com).

Comment: oops, I updated the link to the actual wiki. A large set is a subset of N whose sum of reciprocals diverges. The prime numbers are large for example

Comment: Let $S$ consist of the primes $p > 2$ and consider $(+1,-1,+1,-1,\dots)$.